# How can I determine whether or not a phone can be upgraded to Android 7.XX?

Tags: updates, operating-system

I’m looking at getting an Android phone, and I don’t want to rule out phones that come with Android 5.XX installed if they can be upgraded to 7.XX, but I don’t want to get a phone if it isn’t capable of being upgraded.

Comment: We can't say that. If you want lifetime updates go with Iphone.

Comment: Good to know!  Unfortunately, I have a bit of an aversion to paying Apple's premium for pretty hardware.  Also, I don't want a such a restrictive OS.  I do like the dearth of accessories made for it, though

Comment: Many can - you will for instance find a Cyanogen (sorry, Lineage) Android 7 ROM for something as old as the first generation Moto G, it is just as much a question of the manufacturer deeming it worth supporting it. For Android most phones won't be updated more than one major revision, ie. 4->5 or 5->6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a number of things:

- Check on the manufacturer's of the phone's website for hints or tips on capabilities that come with the phone, hardware specifications and all features of the phone
- Check on technology blogs that do phone reviews e.g "Reviews Tabloid".
- When Android 7.X.X is out check its requirements and compare with the specifications of the phone using Android 5.X.X and see if upgrade is possible.
- Lastly try and find out if the phone allows for OTA updates.